# ViewItem Disposal Issue Inside a Custom Razor Component

Tags: .net, blazor, devexpress, blazor-server-side, devexpress-blazor

I've created a simple custom Razor component, which I'll refer to as HintWrapper.

Inside this HintWrapper, I'm wrapping another DevExpress component - ViewItem.
I'm leveraging standard DevExpress logic to copy a business object.

When I attempt to copy the business object using a standard button, the ViewItem gets disposed of. However, this disposal only occurs when it's encapsulated inside the HintWrapper. If the ViewItem stands alone (i.e., not wrapped by HintWrapper), it remains intact and doesn't get disposed of. Notably, the HintWrapper itself remains undisturbed during the copying process.

Has someone encountered similar problem? What can I do to resolve it?